# Error on creating record odoo

Tags: python-2.7, odoo, odoo-10

I am developing a new model called **hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts**; This is the class declaration:

```
          `class hrWorkShifts(models.Model):
                      _name = 'hr_work_shifts.hr_shifts'
                      _inherit = ['mail.followers','mail.thread','ir.needaction_mixin']`
```

which on create give **integrity error**
:-[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can have this error when you forget a required field in your view and when odoo save the record in database the value is missing.  Check the fields in your view May be you Have forget a required field.

Comment: Don't forget the required field of inherited models too

Comment: Can you post form view and action too check res_model of action did you keep same name of your model